# What is the name of the large island in the D&D world of Nerath?

Tags: dnd-4e

What is the name of the large island in the D&D world of Nerath? I guess it could be a continent also.

[image: Nerath]

Comment: It would seem based on this article http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drdd/20110615  (and a few things in dragon which I can't read)  
The entire land seems to be missing a name, with the lands just having the names of the empires that conquered it. If names were given to the general territory, its beyond my reach :)

Comment: I would put a bounty on this just for the heck of it, but I get the feeling that the answer at this point may well be "It hasn't been named yet", and that wouldn't be much fun. Perhaps we'll know after a few more product releases.

Comment: tweeted #dnd #nerath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The island is called *Kelarnil* based on the following excerpt from *[The Seven Kings of Karkoth](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dragon/399/399_NL_Karkoth.pdf)*

> Karkothi legions menace the fair realms of Vailin, the valiant
>   Seldurian tribes that remain loyal to the old ideal of Nerath, and the
>   great **island of Kelarnil** from their foothold in the **Dread Marches**.

*Dread Marches* is the north east territory on the main island which indeed belongs to Karkoth.

[image]

Comment: impressive! Did you find that for this question, or had you read the document before?

Comment: @GMNoob found it for this question. It's only mention in this one place, as far as I could find (look at the history of edits on the answer).

Comment: Definitely impressive, don't know why I didn't think of searching for the sub names of the parts of the island. Then again, I don't have access to those articles.